# How to fix 'Invalid query format' offset is not allowed in Cube.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cube.js

I'm getting below error when I added **'offset'** property in JSON query of **CubeJS**.

It gives me a proper response when I added only **'limit'** property in JSON query. but gives an error when I added **'limit'** with **'offset'** property.

```
http://localhost:3000/cubejs-api/v1/load?query={
  "dimensions": [
    "Order.driver",
    "Order.ivhTractor",
    "Order.shipper",
    "Order.consignee",
    "Order.division",
    "Order.ordNumber"
  ],
  "timeDimensions": [],
  "filters": [
    {
      "dimension": "Order.ivhTractor",
      "operator": "equals",
      "values": [
        "321"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "limit": 50,
  "offset": 10
}
```

I expect success response which skips 10 records, but getting below error:

```
{
    "error": "Invalid query format: \"offset\" is not allowed"
}
```

Comment: Could you please share which version of Cube.js you use?

Comment: @Pavel I am using npm module **"@cubejs-backend/server-core": "^0.10.16"** for cubeJS backend and as I am using MySQL database hence, also added another npm model which is **"@cubejs-backend/mysql-driver": "^0.10.16"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's due to old version is used. `offset` param was introduced in 0.10.21: https://github.com/cube-js/cube.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#01021-2019-08-05